# How to iterate all of the registry keys?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, registry

I am trying to iterate all the registry key in order to find (contains) and delete jre1.5.0_14 values. Is there a way to do it?

The code below just finds jre1.5.0_14 under a specific key! I do want to iterate all of the keys. By the way if clause gets if it is equal to jre1.5.0_14, but it should be if it contains jre1.5.0_14.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards.

```
@echo off
setlocal 

set KEY_NAME="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad"
set VALUE_NAME=jre1.5.0_14

FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN ('REG QUERY %KEY_NAME%') DO if "%%A"=="%VALUE_NAME%" (

    @echo %%A


)
```

Comment: This might be much easier in a different language, such as python, ruby, vbscript, etc.

Comment: Hi jeffamaphone, thanks for your reply. How can I do this via vbscript?

Comment: With `set KEY_NAME` you set it up to only look in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad`

Comment: @sjoy, how can I make it iterate through root?

Comment: Haven't done this for long time and forgot. *[Here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php)* is Reg query info. See what he says about using correct switches and also under "some examples." You need Regedit to delete. Can start [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/regedit.php#UniqueID).

Comment: It does NOT iterate all the subkeys when I write it like this REG QUERY HKCU /f jre1.5.0_14 /d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this per your last comment. You (probably) need to go through all the keys, and you don't want /d at the end.

If you **know** the string is in a specific key, use this (which I think is what you were originally after):

```
For /f %%a in ('reg query HKCR /f jre1.5.0_14') do (
    rem do deletion here
    echo %%a &&pause
)
```

Use the following to look through all the keys. It runs the query on each key and if "hkey" is found in the output (indicating the query turned up something) it writes the line--the location--to regout.txt. The second for loop goes through each line of the file, where you can do a reg delete command.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    del regout.txt >NUL 2>&1
        for %%a in (HKCU, HKLM, HKU, HKCR) do REG QUERY %%a /f jre1.5.0_14 | FIND /i "hkey" >>regout.txt
        for /f %%a in (regout.txt) do (
             rem do deletion here
            echo %%a &&pause
        )
exit
```

If the file is empty the string wasn't found and you should run regedit in Windows again to confirm it's there.

---

**Edit:** Attempt to resolve "The process can not access the file because the file is being used by another process . . .

Try this code: It uses different file names and creates a tmp file with query output, then copies it to txt. The new txt file should definitely be unlocked.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
del regout.txt >Nul 2>&1
del regout.tmp >Nul 2>&1
del output.txt >Nul 2>&1
    for %%a in (HKCU, HKLM, HKU, HKCR) do REG QUERY %%a /f jre1.5.0_14 | FIND /i "hkey" >>output.tmp
    copy output.tmp output.txt /y
    for /f %%a in (output.txt) do (
        rem do deletion here
        echo %%a &&pause
        del output.tmp
    )
exit
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am getting **The process can not access the file because the file being used by another process** when I run batch file.

Comment: I misread your comment. Do you have regout.txt open? If yes, close it. The batch deletes the file then recreates its, so I'm not sure the problem. It's late where I am, but will check in once more tonight.

Comment: If you have run batch file repeatedly and still same error, try this: Put this line between the two For statements: `taskkill /im notepad.exe 2> nul` (Note: It should kill all instances of notepad, so be sure you save any notepad data you have open)

Comment: can I echo matched results instead of writing to file?

Comment: Not easily the way it's written. What's problem with the taskkill? In fact, put it at top before the `del` line in case that's the problem. I'm testing this here and am not having the problem. Once working ok you can take it out.

Comment: @after taskkill still having the same error. **the process can not access the file ...**

Comment: oK. 1st fix error in my code. Last line shd be &&pause. If still prob, Do you have some java/jre thing open? Try changing jre1.5.0_14 to something else. I've been using sdk. Gotta call it a night. Will check for comment from you tomorrow. ACTUALLY if &&pause fixes it let me know asap. thanks.

Comment: I tried your updated solution but still the same error!

Comment: All I can think, restart your system and try again. This makes no sense.

Comment: could it be some sort of priviledges?

Comment: Very unlikely. Do a search on this error and see what you come up with. Did you restart? That's first. Also, look at task manager and see if something's running that could be tying up file. Get Unlocker utility and see what it says is locked.

Comment: wierd thing is, I can iterate **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services**

Comment: You can iterate it with this code, using the regout.txt file? Searching for what? If so, the file isn't locked and this has been a giant wild-goose chase. Anyway, I posted new code to try.

Comment: Hi @sjoy, here is what I get in the output file...`C:\Users\197199\Desktop>REM for %a in (HKCU, HKLM, HKU, HKCR) do REG QUERY %a /f cenk | FIND /i "hkey" >>regout.txt` 4 same lines

Comment: You're not running from command prompt are you?! If not, sounds like you got some old code in there. Open fresh notepad and carefully copy ALL the new code. Be sure notepad is full-screen wide so nothing wraps. Save with new bat name. Let me know

Comment: @raysefo Just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27287873/3981401). Don't know how much of your trouble was real and how much fictitous, but do think it's time you just accepted the answers you got from people who spent too much time trying to help you and call it a day.

Comment: I am trying to solve this issue not only via batch file.