# How to iterate registry from the root?

Tags: vbscript, registry

I would like to **search all the registry (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, HKEY_USERS and all of the subkeys) for a specific value and if there is a match I would like to delete this entry**. Is there a way to do this? I found a sample like below but it is not iterating all the registry.

Best Regards and thanks in advance.

```
Const HKCU = &H80000001
Const HKLM = &H80000002
Const HKU  = &H80000003

Const REG_SZ = 1
Const REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2
Const REG_BINARY = 3
Const REG_DWORD = 4
Const REG_MULTI_SZ = 7

valueToDelete = "Alex De Souza"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

Sub DeleteFromRegistry(hive, key, searchValue)
  'enumerate values and delete matching ones
  rc = reg.EnumValues(hive, key, values, types)


  If Not IsNull(values) Then

  For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    strValueName = values(i)
    Select Case types(i)

      ' Show a REG_SZ value
      '
      Case REG_SZ          
        reg.GetStringValue hive, key, strValueName, strValue

        If InStr(strValue, searchValue) > 0 Then

            wscript.echo "Found  " & key & ": "& strValueName & " (REG_SZ) = " & strValue
            rc = reg.DeleteValue(hive, key, strValue)

        End If

      ' Show a REG_EXPAND_SZ value
      '
      Case REG_EXPAND_SZ
        reg.GetExpandedStringValue hive, key, strValueName, strValue

        If InStr(strValue, searchValue) > 0 Then

            wscript.echo "Found  "& key & ": " & strValueName & " REG_EXPAND_SZ) = " & strValue
            rc = reg.DeleteValue(hive, key, strValue)
        End If
      ' Show a REG_DWORD value
      '
      Case REG_DWORD
        reg.GetDWORDValue hive, key, strValueName, uValue

        If InStr(strValue, searchValue) > 0 Then

            wscript.echo "Found  "& key & ": " & strValueName & " (REG_DWORD) = " & strValue
            rc = reg.DeleteValue(hive, key, strValue)
        End If

    End Select
  Next

 End If

 'enumerate subkeys and recurse
  rc = reg.EnumKey(hive, key, subkeys)
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      If key = "" Then
        path = sk
      Else
        path = key & "\" & sk
      End If
      DeleteFromRegistry hive, path, searchValue
    Next
  End If

End Sub

'iterate over hives (HKCR can be ignored, because it's just a combining view
'on 2 subkeys of HKLM and HKCU)
For Each hive In Array(HKCU, HKLM, HKU)
  DeleteFromRegistry hive, "", valueToDelete
Next
```

Comment: You're trying to use `DeleteValue` on the *data* (`strValue`) of a registry value (`strValueName`). Use this to delete the value: `reg.DeleteValue(hive, key, strValueName)`. If you want to clear the data of a registry value you need to use the respective setter method, e.g. `reg.SetStringValue(hive, key, strValueName, "")` for string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive procedure for this.

```
Const HKCU = &H80000001
Const HKLM = &H80000002
Const HKU  = &H80000003

valueToDelete = "..."

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv")

Sub DeleteFromRegistry(hive, key, searchValue)
  'enumerate values and delete matching ones
  rc = reg.EnumValues(hive, key, values, types)
  If Not IsNull(values) Then
    For Each val In values
      If val = searchValue Then rc = reg.DeleteValue(hive, key, val)
    Next
  End If

  'enumerate subkeys and recurse
  rc = reg.EnumKey(hive, key, subkeys)
  If Not IsNull(subkeys) Then
    For Each sk In subkeys
      If key = "" Then
        path = sk
      Else
        path = key & "\" & sk
      End If
      DeleteFromRegistry hive, path, valueToDelete
    Next
  End If
End Sub

'iterate over hives (HKCR can be ignored, because it's just a combining view
'on 2 subkeys of HKLM and HKCU)
For Each hive In Array(HKCU, HKLM, HKU)
  DeleteFromRegistry hive, "", valueToDelete
Next
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar Wiechers, thanks for your reply. Before I try your vbs, I would like to know what this line does? RecurseReg hive, "", valueToDelete

Comment: @raysefo Sorry, that should've been `DeleteFromRegistry ...`. I changed the procedure name before posting, but apparently not everywhere.

Comment: I think I should change **RecurseReg** to **DeleteFromRegistry**. After I changed it the way I suggested, it gives not a collection error to line **For Each val In values**

Comment: how can I get rid of this **NOT A COLLECTION** error?

Comment: @raysefo Check the out parameters for `Null` values. See updated answer.

Comment: I am getting **Error 800A01C2 - Wrong number of arguments of invalid property assignment.** at **DeleteFromRegistry hive, key & "\" & sk**

Comment: I guess valueToDelete should be addes.

Comment: Also a big problem is, when script starts searching from **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents**, it does NOT go inside of AppEvents which has **EventLabels** and **Schemes**.

Comment: @raysefo Works fine for me.

Comment: can you get the sub folders of AppEvents? **EventLabels** and **Schemes**??? I tried on a different PC but still NOT  iterating the sub folders of AppEvents.

Comment: @raysefo And their subkeys, yes. I usually test these things before saying "it works".

Comment: this is wierd! How come I can not access those sub folder etc? Is it gonna be some sort of PC settings, authorization etc.?

Comment: Check the return code (`rc`) and check the permissions on the key.

Comment: would you please tell me how to check those?

Comment: How about you start doing some legwork yourself? Variables can be checked with a debugger or by echoing them in the script. Registry permissions can be checked via `Regedit`.

Comment: it seems the permissions are OK for the sub folders.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't sit in front of your computer, so you'll have to start debugging this yourself.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers , I created a fake key/value test1 REG_SZ Alex De Souza under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad and when It tries to delete it gets 2.